# Failed to marshall domain instance [demo.Category : 7] in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, grails, indexing

I have implemented Elastic search in grails 3.3.6. I ran the application I got error - error indexing on category of id 7.

my category domain is,

```
class Category {

static hasMany = [events : Event]
Category parent
String name
String description
User createdBy
User modifiedBy
Timestamp createdDate
Timestamp modifiedDate

def beforeInsert(){
    createdDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
    modifiedDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
}
def beforeUpdate() {
    modifiedDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
}

static constraints = {
    name nullable: false , unique: true
    description nullable: true
    parent nullable: true
    createdBy nullable: false
    modifiedBy nullable: false
    createdDate nullable: true
    modifiedDate nullable: true
    events nullable: true
}
static searchable = true

}
```

my event domain is,

```
package com.grailsbrains
```

import com.grailsbrains.auth.User

import java.sql.Timestamp

class Event {

```
static belongsTo = [category : Category, organization: Organization]
static hasMany = [languages : Language,formats:Format]

String title
String duration
String type
String summary
String prequel
byte[] mainVideo
byte[] mainImage
String tagline
String specialInstruction
String mapUrl
Timestamp startDateTime
Timestamp endDateTime
boolean isEnabled
boolean isExpired
String accessType
String entrance
User createdBy
User modifiedBy
Timestamp createdDate
Timestamp modifiedDate

def beforeInsert(){
    createdDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
    modifiedDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
}
def beforeUpdate() {
    modifiedDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())
}

static searchable = {
    title boost: 2.0
    summary boost: 1.0
    title analyzer: 'simple'
    summary analyzer: 'simple'
    tagline analyzer: 'simple'
    category reference : true
    formats reference: true
    languages reference: true
    except = ['mainImage','mainVideo','createdBy','modifiedBy','createdDate','modifiedDate']
}

static constraints = {
    title nullable: true , unique: true
    startDateTime nullable: true
    endDateTime nullable: true
    mainImage nullable: true
    mainVideo nullable: true
    duration nullable: true
    type nullable: true, blank:false
    summary nullable: true , blank:false
    prequel nullable: true 
    tagline nullable: true 
    specialInstruction nullable: true 
    mapUrl nullable: true 
    isExpired nullable: false
    isEnabled nullable: false
    accessType nullable: true
    entrance nullable: true
    createdBy nullable: true
    modifiedBy nullable: true
    createdDate nullable: true
    modifiedDate nullable: true

}
}
```

I am trying to insert values into category table using API through postman.The data were inserted into table. But I got this error

> 2018-07-31 14:20:15.337 ERROR --- [           main]
>   g.p.e.index.IndexRequestQueue            : Error Indexing class
>   com.grailsbrains.Category (index: com.grailsbrains_write , type:
>   category) of id 7
>   grails.plugins.elasticsearch.exception.IndexException: Failed to
>   marshall domain instance [com.grailsbrains.Category : 7]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)

in my console. Any idea - Can anyone please help me out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get errors in your ES server logs?

Comment: In grails console I got this error - "Failed to marshall domain instance [com.grailsbrains.Category : 7]". Where I will find ES logs?

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. Using the tarball or zip file or through a package manager?

Comment: I have checked with ElasticSearch logs - there is no error.

Comment: What version of ES are you running and what version of the grails elasticsearch plugin?

Comment: I have tried to insert data into event - data were inserted and elasticsearch index is also created for event

Comment: I am using ES-5.4.1 and the grails elasticsearch plugin is 2.4.0

Comment: what about the plugin version?

Comment: grails elasticsearch plugin is 2.4.0

Comment: you need to use root/child functionality I think. As you have dependency belongsTo. Try to play with that. You can find more info in the plugin docs